# How to load Maven project properties in Spring Boot Starter and add to Environment?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-starter

Let's assume there are multiple Spring Boot applications having properties with `@...@` placeholders referring to Maven project properties:

```
spring.application.name=@project.name@
version=@project.version@
...
```

Since it's common to all applications, it would be useful to create a custom Spring Boot starter, to prevent duplication, that would add those properties to the Environment with the lowest precedence.

---

In the custom starter, I added the properties to the `custom.properties` file and created `CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor` to load them:

```java
public class CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    private final PropertiesPropertySourceLoader loader = new PropertiesPropertySourceLoader();

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(
            ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        ClassPathResource path = new ClassPathResource("custom.properties");
        PropertySource<?> propertySource = loadProperties(path);
        environment.getPropertySources().addLast(propertySource);
    }

    private PropertySource<?> loadProperties(ClassPathResource path) {
        Assert.isTrue(path.exists(), () -> "Resource " + path + " does not exist");
        try {
            return this.loader.load("custom-properties", path).get(0);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to load properties configuration from " + path, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, those properties are not covered by resource filtering.
The build part in the applications' `pom.xml` is shown below:

```xml
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

The question is is it possible to cover the starter's properties file by resource filtering? Or is there any other or better way to load properties from `pom.xml` and add them to the Environment before it starts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution to read Maven properties is to use `MavenXpp3Reader` from the `maven-model` dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.6</version>
</dependency>
```

The `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, which adds properties to the Spring Environment, should be defined as follows:

```java
public class CustomEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

  private final MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();

  @Override
  public void postProcessEnvironment(
      ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("pom.xml")) {
      Model model = reader.read(fileReader);

      Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
      properties.put("spring.application.name", model.getName());
      properties.put("version", model.getVersion());
      environment
          .getPropertySources()
          .addLast(new MapPropertySource("custom-properties", properties));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
  }
}
```